# spring surf vs classic spring mvc in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, spring-surf

We are interested in deploy functionality inside Alfresco.

I have noticed that the newest versions of Alfresco Share are based on Spring Surf.
So we have ruled out WebScripts as an option.  Are them old fashioned?

Before start with Spring Surf and in order to be practical: what about extend Alfresco with our own controllers and JSP views?

I’m not familiar with WebScripts or Spring Surf.  It could be so interesting to debate the advantages/disadvantages of using these technologies.

I’ll start with some points related to our team which is used to Java programming.

CLASSIC SPRING MVC / JSP VIEW

Advantages
-   We are familiar with these techlonogies
-   Template hot deployment is possible with JSP.  Ok.  It’s true that JSP aren’t templates, but they will be our view.

SPRING SURF

Advantages
-   Lack of the necessity to know Java programming. Ok but we can program in Java
Disadvantages
-   We have to learn a new technology.
-   Springsource has it in incubation status.  Perhaps we’re going to learn a new technology that won’t achieve success.
-   Is there any project adopting this technology apart from Alfresco?

Thanks in advance.  Best regards
ATV

Answer (score 0):

Tackling one of the sub-questions: Alfresco WebScripts **are** built on top of Spring Surf! A Webscript is an implementation of `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScript`

With WebScripts, you also have the choice of writing your controller in either Java or JavaScript, which I don't believe SpringMVC offers.

Hopefully someone else can advise you on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A big disadvantege of SpringSurf is that you need a webscript, usually with a javascript acting as a controller and the javascript API is much less powerfull than Foundation Services API. Of course, you can write a Java backed webscript to gain access to the foundation API, but this is extra work.

An advantage of SpringSurf is that the look & feel usually appeals more to end users due to the old fashioned look of JSF based UI's comparing to the javascript libraries like http://script.aculo.us/ .